# How to get input value by using class?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am using the code below

```
WebElement inputele = driver.findElement(By.className("class_name"));
String inputeleval = inputele.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(inputeleval);
```

but the value is `empty`. The HTML is below.

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="hiddenresult">
      <div class="tech-blog-list">
         <label for="Question">1st Question</label>
         <input id="txt60" class="form-control" type="text" value="sddf sd sdfsdf sdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsd fsd" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pagination_main pull-left">
      <div id="Pagination">
         <div class="pagination">
            <a class="previous" onclick="PreviousBtnClickEvent();" href="javascript:void(0)">Previous</a>
            <a id="pg59" class="ep" onclick="PaginationBtnClickEvent(this);" href="javascript:void(0)" name="Textbox">1</a>
            <a id="pg41" class="ep" onclick="PaginationBtnClickEvent(this);" href="javascript:void(0)" name="Textbox">2</a>
            <a id="pg40" class="ep" onclick="PaginationBtnClickEvent(this);" href="javascript:void(0)" name="Textarea">3</a>
            <a id="pg60" class="ep current" onclick="PaginationBtnClickEvent(this);" href="javascript:void(0)" name="Textbox">4</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you post HTML, please take a minute to beautify it using a website like http://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/. It makes it much easier to read and helps those investigating see children, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element fully loaded on page and visible as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement inputele= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("class_name")));
String inputeleval = inputele.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(inputeleval);
```

**Note** :-`By.className("class_name")` will give that element which class attribute equal to `class_name`. Make sure which element you want to locate is unique element with class attribute equal to `class_name` otherwise wise it will give first element with condition true.

Hope it will work..:)

Comment: **WebElement inputele= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("class_name")));**

line is failed

Comment: I am using this code in Pagination "for looping" concept , we are using xpath & id, velue is displayed but, id is different (like pg100, pg50, pg49---- pgz), so how to get value by using class name ?

Comment: @Vidya Could you share your HTML??

Comment: @Vidya you need to provide enough information actually what you want...without enough information we could not solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is pretty close but you have the wrong class name? In your code above, you had "class_name" instead of "form-control". I'm assuming that was some sample code and not the actual code you are using? There is only one `INPUT` in the HTML and the code below should work. It also has an ID so that should be more specific in case there are more than one `INPUT`s on the page.

```
WebElement inputele= driver.findElement(By.className("form-control"));
String inputeleval = inputele.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(inputeleval);
```